# If sample size is 20 and I want to know the probability of 2 or less.

Tags: probability-distributions, biology

Am I making harder then it is based on this question:  See my answer below.

F2 population of a plant species (which is a diploid) resulted from a cross between a plant with red flowers and a plant with white flowers. The flower color is controlled by a single gene; each of the parents is homozygous for the gene; the red allele is dominant over the white allele. When you scored 20 F2 plants, what is the probability to have the number of plants with white flowers 
is 2 or fewer?

probability  = 2/20 + 1/20 + 0/20 = 0.15

Comment: You are assuming that we are all familiar with the jargon of your field.  Perhaps you could define the terms you used, so as to make this into more of a math problem.

Comment: What is the probability of any particular plant from the F2 population having white flowers?

Comment: Note: if you could compute $p$, the probability that a single plant has the property you want then (assuming independence) the answer you want is $(1-p)^{20}+\binom {20}1\times p\times (1-p)^{19}+\binom {20}2\times p^2\times (1-p)^{18}$.

Comment: I don't get the question.  Since each of the parent is homozygous of the color gene, one parent is RR, and the other is WW, so the offspring can only have RW.  Since allele R dominates allele W, it must be red.  I'm missing something in genetics?

Comment: It should have nothing to do with genetics as the question possed to the group is not expecte to understand genetics.  Jargon added, I think to confuse the request.   As for (1−p) 20 +(201)×p×(1−p) 19 +(202)×p 2 ×(1−p) 18   How do you solve for p?